# A way to navigate from Main Activity to Second Activity, not using XML files

Tags: android, kotlin

What is **the simplest way** to navigate from First Activity to Second Activity using Kotlin?

Is it possible **not to use** `activity_main.xml` and `activity_second.xml` files?

[image]

Comment: Strictly speaking, you never really _have to_ use layout XML. You could handle all of the `View` instantiation and setup yourself in code. That said, what are you trying to accomplish, exactly? That is, why would you like to do it without layouts? Even if you go that route, though, navigating to another `Activity` is still the same; i.e., `startActivity()` or similar.

Comment: I wanna write a code only in `MainActivity.kt` file, and not spend a time on setup of `xml' files.

Comment: I'm still not quite sure what you're going for. Do you mean that you want only one `Activity`? If so, then you can have a look at `Fragment`s, or otherwise juggling the UI yourself in that one `Activity`. Or, do you mean that you're just trying to avoid layout XML altogether? If that, then there's either the old-fashioned way of instantiating and setting up your `View`s and hierarchy manually, or the new [Jetpack Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose), but that's still in its early stages.

Comment: Yes Mike, I'm trying to avoid layout XML altogether. Please show me how to use Jatpack Compose.

Comment: Well, there's a basic example of the old-fashioned way in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11147748). I've not played with Compose yet, but the link above should be a good place to start. (I also just came across [this neat little site](https://jetc.dev/) today, too, which has some good examples and whatnot.) In either case, I think the main hurdle is just going to be familiarizing yourself with the various available UI components and their capabilities.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Why you not publish it as your answer?

Comment: No problem. I'm good, though. :-) I didn't really do much but provide some links. Nothing major. Thank you, however. I do appreciate the offer. Hope you can find some helpful information in those links (I edited my last comment with another, in case you didn't notice). Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this line of code in your first activity to open your second activity:
`startActivity(Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)`

It doesn't involve your xml views, although if you're using xml as your views, you should use `setContent([your_xml_file])` method to tell your activity that where is their view.